# How can I configure vim to show autocomplete popup without enter command manually?

Tags: linux, vim

Always when I'm editing a `CSS` file and I want get autocomplete, I need enter the command `<C-x><C-o>` to open the suggestions list popup.

How can I configure my `Vim` to open the popup automatically when I'm typing, without enter the command manually?

Comment: the you complete me plugin has that sort of functionality. someone was struggling to use it with css and html over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572220/no-auto-complete-on-html-and-css-files-in-vim-youcompleteme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try one of these:

[MUcomplete](https://github.com/lifepillar/vim-mucomplete) - fast and lightweight

[YouCompleteMe (YCM)](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) - powerful but can be tricky to install

[neocomplete](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim) - I haven't tried it but apparently also very good

Comment: I was using `YCM`, but I couldn't configure it to open popup automatically, so I switch to `neocomplete`, it's awesome